# How to adapt an old template with aidanews module to work in Joomla 3.3.6

Tags: module

My joomla comes from 1.7 version to 3.3.6 and in my project I using AnimalBusiness-TG template that uses the aidanews module on home. By now, this module appear blank and no error message its showed. My phoca gallery appears blank too and I dont know what to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you have to realise is that the difference between Joomla 1.7 and 3.3.x is extremely drastic, therefore there will be a lot of extension that will stop working. What you need to do is, go to the developer site for all 3rd party extensions you're using and install the Joomla 3.x compatible versions for them.

I would suggest you do the same for your template too.

This is all you can do. There's nothing e can do here to help you (code wise) to get your extensions working

Comment: Hi. I fixed some stuffs and the template works (everything, but the aidanews module). This module works ok on administrator, but the only trouble with it happens in the front end part.

Comment: As stated in my answer, you will need to installed the Joomla 3.x compatible version of all 3rd party extension, including **aidanews**

Comment: Sorry, I solved the problem (probably, it´s not the better way, but...) typing a function in the `Class JDate` assigned like `toMySQL($local = false)`. It returns the `__toString()` result!

Comment: The migration from 1.7 to 3.3.6 was done carefully, step-by-step, fixing little differences in the 3rd party extensions (like you said) with the joomla docs beside and I had a good result. Thank you anyway and you´re right, the difference is drastic, but my old project needs to keep working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem typing a function in the `Class JDate` assigned like `toMySQL($local = false)`. It just returns the `__toString()` result!

This function was in the old version of Joomla and this 3rd party module needs it.